# TP-Link HS200: 2 black, 1 red, toggling, and dim

Tags: wiring, smart-switch

Trying to install 4 HS200 in seperate rooms in a new 2017 construction.

The light switch is a simple 1 pole with 1 red, 2 black, 1 ground, and 2 white with a nut inside the box.

The hs200 toggle for three times and only lightly dim the Led fixture (26w) in a sporadic manner[image]
[image]
[image]
[image: Old switch diagram]

Comment: Wow, that's not going to work.  You obviously have huge skill gaps here, as there are so many mistakes it's beyond our Q&A format. Rarely do I say this, but **you need to stop**.  At least, get a book on electrical and read it through before doing any more work. Especially read up on 3-way switches.  Don't try to google it, Google only answers questions, and you need a well-rounded primer on the subject *in order to know which questions to ask*.

Comment: TP-Link Kasa has a 3-way switch, HS210. But in order to properly install these, you need to know how 3-way switches work. It is not enough to be able to move wires from an old switch to a new switch, sometimes people get lucky that way and other times they get dead. You could hire an electrician to install your smart switches.

Comment: Your replies are making me ashamed of myself especially since I had good knowledge of electrical wiring as I was trained academically to do simple wiring. The reason I am confused is that this switch only controls one fixture which is solely controlled by this switch, however the breaker does go to two other room with each a lighting circuit. My understanding of a three way switch is that it allow to control a light from two different switch located on the same circuit, this is not the case.

Comment: Your shame is something to talk about with your therapist, it's not something for us. Meanwhile how you have this connected indicates that you do not have an understanding of household wiring. I suggest a book such as Wiring Simplified to help you to understand what you are doing incorrectly here.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't mean to offend, but based on what you say your skills would be greatly enhanced by getting a practical book on home electrical such as "Wiring Simplified".  Just between you and me, people who have electronics or general electrical knowledge often find it has *wildly mis-trained* them for NEC/code/home electrical practices. Which are very particular in odd ways.  See also "doctors are the worst patients" lol.

Comment: As far as that being a 1-way switch, *maybe* but do an exhaustive search. Have any unexplained switches? Has the function of the switch ever inverted?  /3 cable is also sometimes used where a light+fan might be installed, for separate control of each.   How was the old switch wired?

Comment: So its a single pole switch with two black to one screw and 1 red wire to the other screw. It is grounded by its mounting screws

Comment: Please [edit] in a picture of the old switch, preferably with all the wiring attached before you started this process. Also, mistakes are nothing to be ashamed of, but remember that mistakes with electrical and gas can _kill_ you, so be sure to do research _before_ starting.

Comment: So I had added a picture of the old switch diagram. This is exactly how it currently plugged. After failing to install the HS200, I reverted to the old switch and I am back to the original install. Any new insight might help as I have read and watched Youtube video regarding the purpose, wiring and specifics of 3 ways switch circuits, at first glance, there is no reason why there would be a three way switch circuit other than feeding  power to other switches on the same breaker which I noted in my first comment. Any other suggestion would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have enough information to make a good guess as to why there's a /3 cable in the box (the cable with the red wire). Based on your illustration with the toggle switch, it appears to be configured to send always-hot power on the black wire and switched-hot power on the red wire. Connect the smart dimmer in the same way. In more words:

- Add the dimmer's white neutral wire into the wire nut with the two existing white wires
- Remove the two black wires from the toggle switch. Connect the two of them, and either one of the black wires from the dimmer, with a wire nut.
- Remove the red wire from the toggle switch and connect it to the remaining black wire of the dimmer.
- It appears the smart dimmer won't get a suitable ground simply by being mounted to the metal box, so connect its green wire to that screw in the back of the box along with the bare copper ground wire.

Comment: This worked! I did the exact same wiring as you mentioned and it works perfectly.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think any of the newer switches (smart or not) are self-grounding. I've put in a number of Decora style switches lately, particularly dimmers, and they've all got a green pig-tail.

Comment: @AlfredEid If this answer has resolved your problem, the appropriate thing to do is click the check mark and the up arrow. That's the appropriate way of saying "thank you".

Comment: Much thanks to @Greghill ! Upvoted and checked. Also it is not self grounding as it has plastic screw holes, I grounded the ground wire to the back of the box in a C shape clock wise manner.